# Fine structure of bifurcation diagram of logistic family

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-dynamical-systems

I'd like to learn about the period-doubling route to chaos of the logistic family $f_\lambda(x)= \lambda x (1-x)$ and got interested in the fine properties of the bifurcation diagram of this family as we vary $\lambda$.

On wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map they claim that for most parameters $\lambda \in [3.56995, 4]$ that $f_\lambda$ is chaotic, except for some islands of stability.

> Can we classify those islands of stability?

Also it is claimed that if we zoom in around $\lambda=3.82843$ (the end of what they call the Pomeau–Manneville scenario) then we roughly recover the original bifurcation diagram.

> Do you know a reference for the proof of this self-similarity?

In case you are aware of any paper discussing the bifurcation diagram for the logistic map in detail, please let me know.

Comment: Are there no papers cited at that Wikipedia page?

Comment: @GerryMyerson There is a paper listed for a particular value ($\lambda = 1+\sqrt{8}$) where an island of stability starts. However, none for where they are located in general. No paper is mentioned for the self-similarity.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/361637/37099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions you are asking are fundamental to the theory of one-dimensional dynamical systems.  I would suggest starting with an introductory textbook, such as *An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems* by Devaney. Books with more in-depth results include *Iterated Maps of the Interval as Dynamical Systems* by Collet and Eckmann, and *One-Dimensional Dynamics* by Melo and van Strien.

By the way, the islands of stability you mention are related to [Sharkovskii's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharkovskii%27s_theorem) and [Milnor-Thurston kneading theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milnor%E2%80%93Thurston_kneading_theory), both of which are covered in Devaney's book.  The self-similarity is a result of something called "renormalization" (which as far as I know is not related to the concept with the same name in quantum field theory).

Comment: Indeed, I am reading Devaney's book and there he makes the claim that those islands exist without giving a proof. I do have Collet and Eckmann's book on the shelf in my office, will check it out tomorrow.

Comment: I must admit that I do not see the connection between the islands of stability and the kneading theory. Maybe I need to have another look at the relevant chapter, but it seemed to me that Devaney only elaborates on the period-doubling cascade and not on the connection to those islands.